# jQuery remove new elements

Tags: jquery, html

I've got an HTML form that allows the user to add more elements to the form, but by the side of each line of elements, there is a 'Remove' button, this button is linked to a jQuery call but the newly added elements aren't removing when the button is clicked, however, the elements that were originally hard coded into the HTML will remove.

Here is my code:

```
$("[data-action]").each(function(i,a){
$(a).bind('click',function(){
    switch ($(a).attr("data-action")) {
        case "AddQualificationField":
            qual_add_current++;
            var qual_add_html = '<div id="AddQualification' + qual_add_current + '" class="controls inline" style="margin-top: 5px;">' +
                        '<label for="AddQualificationType[' + qual_add_current + ']">Type:</label> <input type="text" name="AddQualificationType[' + qual_add_current + ']" id="AddQualificationType[' + qual_add_current + ']" placeholder="e.g. \'A\' Level" class="input-small" maxlength="75" /> ' +
                        '<label for="AddQualificationSubject[' + qual_add_current + ']">Subject:</label> <input type="text" name="AddQualificationSubject[' + qual_add_current + ']" id="AddQualificationSubject[' + qual_add_current + ']" class="input-small" maxlength="75" /> ' +
                        '<label for="AddQualificationGrade[' + qual_add_current + ']">Grade:</label> <input type="text" name="AddQualificationGrade[' + qual_add_current + ']" id="AddQualificationGrade[' + qual_add_current + ']" class="input-small" maxlength="20" /> ' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn" data-action="RemoveQual" data-qualid="' + qual_add_current + '"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>' +
                    '</div>';
            $("fieldset#AddQualifications").append(qual_add_html);
            break;

        case "RemoveQual":
            var qual_id = parseInt($(a).attr("data-qualid"));
            if (confirm("Are you sure that you want to do this?")) {
                $("div#AddQualification" + qual_id).remove();
            }
            break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: We can't fix the code if you don't show it.

Comment: [**Be specific**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer. So, what have you tried? **Show some code!**

Comment: I've added my code now

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Jquery [On](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to remove dynamically created elements.

Comment: @MarkEriksson This is the correct answer, albeit there should have been more of an explanation and a code example. You just used `.on()` incorrectly, however you tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *re-bind* the elements you dynamically add to the DOM tree. The first *bind()* call only binds the element that are currently in your document. The elements added after are not considered.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being a pain in the arse, I've managed to fix it myself -- thanks for your help though.

I just used `onclick="javascript:RemoveQual(' + qual_add_current + ');"` on the remove button.